# Formatting Y axis numbers in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I managed to format my y axis text to two decimals, but since I'm using very large numbers, is there a way I can display my numbers like:

```
NAD 100,000,000.00
```

rather than

```
NAD 100000000.00
```

by using tick options

```
yaxis: { 
           tickOptions:{formatString:'NAD %.2f'} 
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually does....

```
tickOptions:{
               formatString:"NAD %'d "
            }
```