# Why is the Number being Displayed with Comma is wrong place?

Tags: javascript, c#, jqplot

Im grabbing the data from jqplot chart

```
        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info1').html("Day " + ticks[pointIndex] +  " - " + plot1.series[seriesIndex].label + ": $" + data);
            }
        );
```

It's displaying the number as this:

```
Day 6 - Online: $6,46267.9
Day 6 - Cheque: $6,60056.39
```

Numbers are like this in the arrays:

```
660056.39
646267.9
```

How do I stop it from presenting the number with that weird comma, and show the numbers correctly?

Comment: try with typecasting

Comment: Looks like a setting to me. Weirdest one I've seen in a while, but a setting nonetheless.

Comment: You need to look at the jqplot documentation, and figure out how to format numbers properly there.  Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16436132.  Probably the `formatString` property, which apparently models `printf`.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: The `formatString` options are described in detail in the documentation here: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

Comment: Maybe your number overflows a decimal, try using your number's as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

```
var money1 = String(data).replace(/,/g , '');
var money = money1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

Edit:

```
 var money1 = String(data).split(",")[1];
 var money = money1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

Turns out the number before the comma was just the x-axis label. Not apart of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/) (A javascript library for formatting and manipulating numbers). You can then unformat or format the data as you wish.

$('#info1').html("Day " + ticks[pointIndex] +  " - " + plot1.series[seriesIndex].label + ": $" + **unformat(data)**);

Comment: Or, you can use `formatString`, which already exists in jqplot.